# Write MongoDB _id value to JSON from iOS

Tags: ios, json, mongodb

I am creating a JSON-format string in Objective-c/iOS.  How can I write an _id element that is compliant with a MongoDB _id field structure (type3 binary)?

Comment: There's no objectid type in JSON. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to create a JSON document in iOS that I can write directly into MongoDB (via a web service).

Comment: So what is wrong with this question to be down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mongo Extended JSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON) documentation says that this should be JSON representation of ObjectIds

```
{ "$oid" : "50129aff7f8adfda54f955a1" }
```